# Splash screen blur when using react native with expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

When I opened my splash screen on gallery it looks fine, no blur, but why when I add it to my react native expo project it looks like this? can I use svg for my splash?

[image]

here's code on my `app.json`.

```
{
  "name": "thisisname",
  "displayName": "thisisname",
  "expo": {
    "name": "thisisname",
    "slug": "thisisname",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "nameofpackage"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Expo splash image must be PNG according to https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/config/app/#image
2. You should show us the difference between the way the splash screen looks in your gallery VS how it looks on your project..
3. try to enhance the image quality